# Extern structure without headers

Tags: c, extern

I have to different files : main.c and source.c. I want to scanf and printf information in main.c file, but to work with structure in source.c. I don't know how to use structure in another file without using headers. I've tryied to use extern, but that was totally wrong.
 Can you teach me how to use extern when we talk about structure
For example (just example)

```
main.c 
typedef struct Node{
  int n;
  int p[22];
  int z[33];
}Node;

Node a;

void sum (int i,int j, Node *sum);

main(){
   int i,j;
   scanf("%d",&i); 
   scanf("%d",&J); 
   sum (i,j,&a)
   printf("%d",a.k);
   return 0;
}
```

```
source.c

extern Node a;

void sum (int i,int j, Node *sum){
   a.n = i+j;
}
```

Comment: `typodef` is a nice typo!

Comment: "I don't know how to use structure in another file without using headers." Why do not want to use a header, especially if the code is going to be shared between two C files?

Comment: your `sum()` function doesn't even uses `Node *sum` parameter

Comment: You are using just `main()` what's about function return data type???

Comment: `Node a` is a global variable just for no valid reason

Comment: Your `Node` datatype has only `n`, `p` and `z` as members, no `k`.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to ignore the part that you do not want to use headers, because I suspect that is based on a misunderstanding.

You need to do the declaring and the typedefs in a header, using `extern` (if necessary, but globals are discouraged anyway).
The using and any definitions are in .c files, which `#include` the headers.

main.c

```
/* remove this ... to header
typedef struct Node{
  int n;
  int p[22];
  int z[33];
}Node;
*/
#include "myheader.h"

Node a;

/* remove this ... to header
void sum (int i,int j, Node *sum);
*/

int main(void) /* cleaner prototype */
{
   int i,j;
   scanf("%d",&i); 
   scanf("%d",&J); 
   sum (i,j,&a)
   printf("%d",a.n); /* I use n instead of k, because I do not see that... */
   return 0;
}
```

source.c

```
/* remove this ... completely
extern Node a;
*/
#include "myheader.h"
void sum (int i,int j, Node *sum){

   sum->n /* not sure where the k was meant to be */ = i+j;
   /* use the parameter pointer, use -> */
}
```

myheader.h

```
typedef struct Node{
  int n;
  int p[22];
  int z[33];
}Node;

void sum (int i,int j, Node *sum);
```

Note, I agree with Darth-Codex, that global variable is unneeded here (because the pointer parameter provides all needed access) and that a cleaner `main()` prototype should be used (and whatever else I may find....). And that means that the global could better be replaced by a main-local.

Comment: You should not promote non standard C practices in your answers.

Comment: Just to add -- since a header is a simple case of "pasting" source code into a file, you could as well truly paste (duplicate) the struct definition manually. Not that that's recommended, of course, but that is in fact what an include is doing. Because of the one definition rule the two struct definitions must be "token-identical" (i.e., differ only in whitespace amount), iirc.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX I totally agree. What are you referring to?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, but as I wrote. I do not think that avoiding headers at all cost is actually what OP wants.

Comment: You could also elaborate on when a true struct definition is needed (when you want to create an object or access a member), and when knowing that's a type is sufficient (by forward-declaring it), namley when we only copy pointers around.

Comment: @Yunnosch I know and I agree -- but still ;-). There is the occasional corner case when you indeed don't want to pull in a header, for some reason, and declare things manually.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I agree that it could be discussed. My gut feeling says (assuming I guessed right about headers are in fact OK...) that the scope of my answer matches OPs situation. I would probably upvote other answers which go into the details you mention.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX I think you might mean the use of a global. Yes, I agree (and credited to you) that it is not needed and better avoided. I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: I just noticed the missing return type for main. Did add. (this is why I often avoid providing full code answers, you risk getting bitten).